# Deprecation warning with has_many declaration and :uniq with no other parameters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, deprecation-warning

So I've found out that

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Goal.has_many 
:donors declaration are deprecated: :uniq. Please use a scope block 
instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 
'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

However I have many lines of code where `uniq` is the only parameter such as: 
`has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts, uniq: true`

How would I write this in a block? I've tried `has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts, -> { uniq }` however I read that uniq can't be written like this at the end of the line of code

Comment: I think uniq option is deprecated on rails 4. did you upgrade the version of rails ?

Comment: I did and it is deprecated however, supposedly you can wrap it in a block or use a lambda, I'm asking if you know how I'd write that in rails 4?

Comment: its correct `has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts, -> { uniq }` .

Comment: are you getting  any error or wrong data ?

Comment: It works now, thanks!